# Cannot get user details from post in restfb using java

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

Recently I've been struggling with getting user information from post_id with java. I'm new in restfb, but after reasearching, below code should work. All available permissions are granted. Even in Graph API Explorer when writing post_id I cannot retrieve post's author details.
This is how I do it:

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(token);
String command = "orangepolska/feed";
Connection<Post> pagePosts = facebookClient.fetchConnection(command, Post.class);
ArrayList<String> postList = new ArrayList<String>();
String row;
for( List<Post> posts : pagePosts){
    for (Post post : posts) {
        if (post.getCreatedTime().after(startDate) && post.getCreatedTime().before(endDate)){
            String message = post.getMessage();
            CategorizedFacebookType postedBy = post.getFrom();
            Post.Comments comments = post.getComments();
            row = " owner: "+postedBy.getName()+" owner_id: "+postedBy.getId()+" post: "+message+" + " likes: "+post.getLikesCount() + "\n";
            System.out.println(row);
            postList.add(row);
        }
    }
}
return postList;
```

The problem occurs with various of functions like: getName(), getID(), getLikesCount() etc - these return null.

How can i fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the feed with the fields parameter so Facebook knows which fields you need to be filled. RestFB can only provide access to information that are given by Facebook ;)

Have a look here: http://restfb.com/#selecting-specific-fields

Answer (score 0):

Norbert is correct but the link he posted did not work for me - you need to include "Parameter.with("fields", "from")" to get the user information.

`Connection<Post> pagePosts = facebookClient.fetchConnection(command, Post.class, Parameter.with("fields", "from"));`